# mypy error when setting a variable of a class with a custom setter

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a python module that looks as following:

```
from typing import Union, Sequence, List

class TestClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self._comments = []

    @property
    def comments(self) -> List[str]:
        return self._comments

    @comments.setter
    def comments(self, comments: Union[str, Sequence[str]]):
        if isinstance(comments, list):
            self._comments.extend(comments)
        elif isinstance(comments, str):
            self._comments.append(comments)

testclass_instance = TestClass()
testclass_instance.comments = "test_comment"
```

When I evaluate this with mypy, I get the error message `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "List[str]")`. I assume that this is due to mypy evaluating the comments property as a regular property with the type being `List[str]`, instead of also allowing for regular strings as setters as is defined in the `comments.setter` decorated method. Adjusting the module as following works again:

```
from typing import Union, Sequence, List

class TestClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.comments = []

    @property
    def comments(self) -> str:
        if isinstance(self._comments, str):
            return self._comments
        elif isinstance(self._comments, list):
            return ", ".join(self._comments)
        else:
            raise RuntimeError

    @comments.setter
    def comments(self, comments: str):
        self._comments = comments

testclass_instance = TestClass()
testclass_instance.comments = "test_comment"
```

because now the return value of the property matches the values it is called with again. Issuing `testclass_instance.comments = ["test_comment"]` in the last line here also results in the same kind of error: `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[str]", variable has type "str")`

How can I define class properties with ambiguous setter inputs and the same setter outputs without causing mypy to raise an error?

Comment: It makes me cry for last 4 months at least, but you [cannot](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3004) do it. Asymmetric properties are not supported by `mypy` yet (issue is open 6 years ago, active, high-priority, but...)

Comment: The workaround is to use descriptors, but it will be too verbose. Check [this playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=dfd6117c5609687c6a6310110317715c) for example of such.